# Read http status code by fsockopen

Tags: php, http, url, fsockopen

according to @JoyceBabu on this post [Get http-statuscode without body using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236135/get-http-statuscode-without-body-using-curl/27236181?noredirect=1#comment42949733_27236181) it should be possible to get the http status code of a URL with fsockopen.

So I took the code from @JoyceBabu which works:

```
    <?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if ($fp) {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.google.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6\r\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    $tmp = explode(' ', fgets($fp, 13));
    echo $tmp[1];
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Then I changed the URL to read to www.raffiniert.biz/aktuell:

```
    <?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.raffiniert.biz", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if ($fp) {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.raffiniert.biz/aktuell\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6\r\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    $tmp = explode(' ', fgets($fp, 13));
    echo $tmp[1];
    fclose($fp);
}
```

which returns http 400 - this is not correct.

Another example: www.raffiniert.biz/kunden returns 301. This should be 403.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Raphael

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
$out .= "Host: www.raffiniert.biz/aktuell\r\n";
```

is the problem.

In an HTTP GET, the `Host` header is just that, the host (domain name), and the path within the host is provided in the `GET` line. You should write it like this instead:

```
$out = "GET /aktuell HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out .= "Host: www.raffiniert.biz\r\n";
```

---

About the updated information:

> Another example: www.raffiniert.biz/kunden returns 301. This should be 403.

`www.raffiniert.biz/kunden` gives a 301, which redirects to `www.raffiniert.biz/kunden/` (with a trailing slash), which gives the 403. A browser will do that redirection automatically (i.e. it will send two consecutive requests), and hide the 301.

If you request woth `"GET /kunden/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"` you'll get that 403 directly.

Comment: I see, the GET line in my code was the "/"... I am tired, sorry :) anyhow, it doesn't work on some URLs, I collect some examples

Comment: thanks, I saw that in the meantime. Now that is a fast solution, but it should resolve the final redirect...

Answer (score 0):

Below will give you an return of 200

I've updated the 4'th and 5'th line requesting the get of /aktuell

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.raffiniert.biz", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if ($fp) {
    $out = "GET /aktuell HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.raffiniert.biz\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6\r\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    $tmp = explode(' ', fgets($fp, 13));
    echo $tmp[1];
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't cut/paste a big blob of code without explaining WHAT you've changed.

Comment: If you run it several times you will notice that it is switching back and forth from 301 to 200. It's probably a server thing. It probably is not done processing the request thus resulting in a different code.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use curl?